# What's the relationship between vmlinuz and ISO image (netboot)?

Tags: kernel, iso, pxe, netboot

Why can't I use vmlinuz and initrd from the newest release of kernel 5.11 while the default netboot  image used in PXE is 5.4?

Comment: You must mean the kernels of some particular Linux distribution - what is its name? [The latest upstream kernel release is 5.14.10](https://www.kernel.org/) as of yesterday.

Comment: The distro is Ubuntu. 
But that's not really important - the way I see it. I just want to understand the relationship when PXE booting vmlinuz used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the vmlinuz and initrd are inside the ISO image (no matter if you use the ISO image for netboot, or something else).

So the netboot ISO image for 5.4 will have the vmlinuz and initrd from 5.4.

If you want vmlinuz and initrd from 5.11, you'll need a netboot ISO image made from the files in 5.11. If you can't download one, you'll need to make one (google, there should be a standard process how to make one for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

While the initrd file often includes a number of kernel modules, it usually won't contain all of them.

The netboot image sets up a more complete root filesystem that includes the full `/lib/modules/` directory tree: if you use a newer kernel, the appropriate `/lib/modules/<kernel-version-number>/` directory for it won't exist in the image, and so any attempts of loading kernel modules after the initramfs boot phase will fail, unless the modules are specially prepared with "weak dependencies" *and* the kernel ABI has not had any incompatible changes.

That would, in turn, mean the kernel failing to support "non-essential" hardware, or hardware that is hot-plugged later, or any filesystems and other kernel features that are delivered as modules and are not loaded in the initramfs boot phase.

Newer kernels might also require correspondingly newer user-space tools to make use of new kernel features, although this would be less likely to cause immediate failures than the above-mentioned lack of kernel modules of the correct kernel version.

Of course, nothing prevents you from preparing a custom netboot image with the modules of a newer kernel version included, if you are willing to do the work required.

---

In Ubuntu's netboot ISO, the kernel modules are packaged as separate squashfs images on the ISO (`casper/extras/modules.squashfs-generic` and `casper/extras/modules.squashfs-generic-hwe` on `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso`). The `modules.squashfs-generic` contains modules for the packaged `5.4.0-81-generic` kernel, while `modules.squashfs-generic-hwe` contains modules for the `5.11.0-27-generic` HardWare Enablement kernel (!).

There are even corresponding `hwe-vmlinuz` and `hwe-initrd` files available in the `casper` directory of the ISO: if you use those instead of the regular `vmlinuz` and `initrd` files in your PXE boot configuration, you'll actually get kernel version `5.11.0-27-generic`. It's just that the [commonly distributed Ubuntu netboot instructions](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510) neglect to mention that this option exists.

If that is not new enough for you, it should be possible to make a customized netboot ISO by adding a `casper/extras/modules.squashfs-*` file containing the modules of the newer kernel, and using that instead of the standard one. The required customizations, if any, to the initrd file "will be left as an exercise for the reader."
(translation: I have not done this, but it seems it should be possible with a reasonable amount of effort.)

Comment: Is it possible to take the `mini.iso` from [Netboot Ubuntu Focal](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/) replace the kernel and initrd.gz with the kernel version `5.11`?

Comment: The initrd.gz file on the `mini.iso` is not the same as `casper/initrd` on the `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso`. You can use the `lsinitramfs` command to view a listing of the contents of the "initrd" files. The `initrd.gz` of the `mini.iso` includes the essential parts of the installer, while the live-server ISO brings it in as a separate `casper/installer.squashfs` file. To create a `mini.iso`-style `initrd.gz` with kernel 5.11, you would have to set up a build environment for the Ubuntu mini.iso installer and let it build you a new `initrd.gz`, or unpack, modify & re-pack the old one.

Comment: I know initrd.gz and `casper/initrd` is not the same. But shouldn't it be possible to just replae them? Or is the initrd.gz linked specifically to the mini.iso in this case?

Thanks so much for your time. Do you have any resources for this @telcoM?

Comment: Yes, you can "just replace" `initrd.gz`... but only with an initramfs file that includes the essential parts **of the installer**. On live server media, these installer parts are not in `casper/initrd` but in a separate `casper/installer.squashfs`. And the initrd.gz of the mini.iso seems to use the old Debian-installer environment, which is not quite the same as the initramfs environment of a regular installed OS nor of a live media that uses the `casper` system. Feel free to use `lsinitramfs` to list the contents of each initrd file if you don't believe me.